# External hard drive not recognized in OS

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

my Hitashi external hard drive is not being recognized by any OS.
On windows when i go to "disk managment" section, i have the partition as "NON INITIALISED/ NON ALLOCATED". no other operation on that partion is possible

Any ideas please?

**EDIT**
(Copied from a comment from OP)

> in fact, at the begenning, windows invite me to initialise it but when i clik ok, it says ERROR, cyclyc redondance..

Comment: Try to find some drivers for your device. Go to official page, maybe you will find smtg there.

Comment: Is that classic HDD (spining) or SSD? Or post model number.

Comment: its a classi HDD , model no : 0S00232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you added (very important) I guess Windows showed you `Data error (cyclic redundancy check).` message as on this screenshot:
[image]

In such case with a highest probability your hard disk is failing. Install some S.M.A.R.T. tools. For example [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) or [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_S.M.A.R.T._tools). There check the health of your disk and possibly run internal test or surface check.

[Cyclic redundancy check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) (CRC) is an error-detecting code. If data are read with errors from the drive then CRC will detect the errors.

Comment: thats right! i have that same error, i have downloaded SpeedFan but i don't see how can i use it to correct the problem !

Comment: @MisterUser: SpeedFan will show you the "health" of your disk to confirm the problem. If it does not show that the disk is failing try to run the test. If you see that sectors are being re-allocated then your hard drive is dead or going to be dead very soon and it is unusable. You can claim your warranty or discard the disk. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to Initialize HDD before first use or if it's wiped clean. In Windows `Disk Management`, right click on name of that disk and select `Initialize Disk`, then follow Wizard.

Comment: unfortunately i can't initialize it. when right click, only properties section is available.

Comment: @user267781: Did you right-click the disk? (not the empty space on the disk)

Comment: in fact, at the begenning, windows invite me to initialise it but when i clik ok, it says ERROR, cyclyc redondance.. and by the way the partition only shows on the bottom list not the upper one

Comment: when right clik as you said, the "initialise" action is deactivated

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use DISKPART to initialize a hard disk.

> Open up the Start Menu and type “diskpart” in the run box. Press enter. You’ll be prompted by the Windows UAC to authorize admin access to the DISKPART tool.
>
> A command-prompt-like window will open up, only the prompt will say “DISKPART”. At that prompt, type “list disk”.
>
> [image]
>
> In the list output on our machine you can see the computer’s hard drive (119GB) and the removable SD card (14GB). It is absolutely critical you note the proper disk number. DISKPART commands are immediate and without any warning. If you type in the wrong disk number, you’re going to have a really bad time.
>
> After identifying your HDD’s disk number, enter the following command “select disk #” where # is the disk number of your HDD.
>
> [image]
>
> Whatever commands you execute after this point will only make changes to the selected disk; now would be a good time to double check you’ve selected the right disk just to be extra safe.
>
> Next, now enter the command “clean”
>
> [image]
>
> The clean command zeroes out the sectors of the disk that contain the partition data.
>
> After cleaning the disk, enter the following command “create partition primary”
>
> [image]
>
> Type **format quick fs=ntfs**, press Enter
>
> Type **assign**, press Enter
>
> Now type **exit**, to exit from DISKPART.

[image]

Comment: when i perform create partition primary i get "Cyclic Redundancy Check Error"

Comment: The disk was not listed however there was a gap (disk 0, disk 2) and I could select disk 1.  However the clean command complained that a rescan was needed even though rescan didn't help.